# Integer Casting in dealing with strings in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have what I hope to be a pretty simple problem. I'm very simply trying to convert a char to it's lowercase version. Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender { 
    [outputLabel setText:[inputField text]];
    NSString* textFieldString = [inputField text];
    NSLog(@"String is %@", textFieldString);
    int textFieldLength = textFieldString.length;
    UniChar* currChar = [textFieldString characterAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"First char is %c", currChar);
    NSLog(@"Length is %i", textFieldLength);
    //currChar = [currChar lowercaseString];
    //NSLog(@"Lowercase char is %c", currChar);
}
```

It's giving me a the following error:

> Initialization makes pointer from
>   integer without a cast on the line: 
>   `NSString* currChar = [textFieldString characterAtIndex:0];`

However, when looking in the documentation, it says that the method `characterAtIndex:` returns a char, not an integer. What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`characterAtIndex` returns `unichar` which is an `unsigned short`.  The line should be

```
unichar currChar = [textFieldString characterATtIndex:0];
```

Also, you can just use `lowercaseString` to get the lowercase of the entire `NSString`:

```
NSString *lowercase = [textFieldString lowercaseString];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the definition for that function:

```
- (unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

A unichar is a c data type, and is not a NSString *.  You need to do

```
unichar currChar = [textFieldString characterAtIndex:0];
```

The message you're getting is due to it trying to cast the integer value of the unichar to a pointer value.

EDIT:

BTW, if you really need a NSString back from that the easiest way would probably be (dry-code):

```
NSString *currChar = [textFieldString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
```